# Node.js: zlib.gzipSync()

Tags: node.js, zlib

I have a few questions on `zlib` module, to be used with files under 40MB:

1. What kind of options should be used in `zlib.gzipSync()` for fastest zipping (compression level does not matter)?
2. Which default values is used, if [options](https://nodejs.org/api/zlib.html#zlib_options) is not passed to the method?
3. Is this method returns `Buffer`?
4. What kind of extension and mime type should be used for final result?
5. **Update**: How to pass a file name? (So after unzipping file has name and extension)

Asked because [reference](https://nodejs.org/api/zlib.html#zlib_zlib_gzipsync_buf_options) is not expressive.

Comment: What *exactly* are you trying to do?  Where does your data come from, and where is it supposed to go?

Comment: @josh3736 came from emails as attachments, goes to FS, but via other lib which accepts `Buffer`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [docs describe the `options` object](https://nodejs.org/api/zlib.html#zlib_options) used for every zlib call.  They also point you to the [zlib manual](http://zlib.net/manual.html#Advanced) which describes those options in great detail.

The *fastest* `level` is `0`, which means **no** compression.  However, this would be silly, since you may as well skip gzipping altogether.  `1` means "some compression with best speed."

That said, **don't use `gzipSync`**.  We don't do things synchronously in node.  If you're looking to write the compressed data to a file, do:

```
var compressor = zlib.createGzip({level: 1});
compressor.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('output.gz'));

compressor.end(inputData);
```

Comment: I'm looking to get `Buffer` out of this method, what about passing original filename?

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, not much to go on in that documentation.

I recommend that you look at the [zlib manual](http://zlib.net/manual.html) (the zlib.h source file) for information on the noted parameters and operations.

The fastest compression would be level 1.

The default compression level is 6.  Other defaults can be found in zlib.h.

There does not appear to be an interface to `deflateSetHeader()`, which would be required to insert a file name in a gzip header.